# Accessing a value from a different js file in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I use the variable below **theId** from file1 in another js file2 in react?

**file1.js**
import .....

```
    class File1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      file: "1",
    
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false, 
  
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    var theId = this.state.file 
    console.log("File rowid: " + theId);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  handleChange = event => {

    this.setState({ file: event.target.value });
  };

  Etc...
```

**file2.js**

import ....

```
const File2 = () => {

  const [chart, setChart] = useState([])
  
  var **myId** = file1.theID //  Here is where I want to use the value from File1

  var baseUrl = "https:// xxxxxxxxx"+**myId**;


etc...
```

[here is the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7hXa.png)
How can I call it in file2.js?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you please post the project structure? We need this information to help you!

Comment: It very much depends on how you're managing state in your application. Is `file2` a separate component? Where in the component tree is it? Can you pass the state in as a prop to it? Are you going to need to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a parent to share it, or do you need to look towards a different method of state management like context, or recoil, or redux, or...?

Comment: Check out this tutorial it may help you.

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil and Andy I have updated the codes.

Comment: @Mubo which tutorial are talking about?  maybe you forgot to put the link